# Why can I access const before declaration in exported module

Tags: ecmascript-6, import, module, export, hoisting

I'm having this question, since const variables are not hoisted and a syntax error should be thrown.

Why does this code work?

```
export let testModule = () => {
    let test = document.querySelector('.test');
    test.innerHTML = myText;
    test.style.cssText = 'color: red';
}

const myText = 'IT WORKS!!!!!'
```

I've attached the working plunk if you want to check for yourself: https://plnkr.co/edit/TR8SvCjQgqPDWpI3?preview

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why can I access const before declaration in exported module

Because `testModule()` isn't called until later and `const myText` is defined in a reachable scope by the time the function is called.

Comment: Great answer! I realized this too when talking with some colleagues, but wanted to double-check.